# Integrating a family of vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, integration

Let $X$ be a measure space, or even a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose I have a family of finite-dimensional vector spaces $\{V_x\}_{x\in X}$ indexed by $X$.  Is there any way to "integrate" this family over $X$ (subject to niceness conditions on it) to obtain some sort of "vector-space-like object" $\int V_x \,dx$ possessing a "dimension" (in general not an integer), such that

$$\mathrm{dim} \left(\int V_x \,dx\right) = \int (\mathrm{dim}\, V_x)\,dx \;?$$

Bonus points if there is some category-theoretic way to view $\int V_x\,dx$ as a "coproduct" of the family $\{V_x\}_{x\in X}$.

Comment: Is there a uniform bound on $\dim(V_x)$?

Comment: Have you tried the literature on measurable fields of Hilbert spaces (as used in e.g. representation theory of various groups)? I am not sure if it is quite what you are looking for

Comment: As Yemon says, direct integrals provide one way to do something like this, but they require your $V_x$ to come equipped with an inner product. Is that the case?

Comment: At least in the case $X=\mathbb{N}$ (equipped with the counting measure), there also is a universal property of the direct integral in the category of Hilbert spaces, analogous to the usual finite biproducts of vector spaces: it characterizes the direct integral both as something like a weighted limit and something like a weighted colimit. I haven't worked this out for general $X$ yet, and I'm also not sure about whether the 'something like' in the previous sentence could be removed. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @TobiasFritz No, my $V_x$ have no inner products that I know of.

Comment: @YemonChoi Offhand I don't know of a reason why there would always be such a uniform bound in my examples, but it'd probably happen reasonably often by accident, so I'd certainly be interested in answers that require such a bound.

Comment: (In case it's useful, my $X$ will usually be a *compact* subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: Assuming $X$ is endowed with a finite measure and the spaces $V_x$ vary measurably, one can consider the family as a module over the finite von-Neumann algebra $L^\infty(X)$. Then the dimension function you seek is the so called von-Neumann dimension of this module.

Comment: @UriBader That sounds interesting, can you give more details and citations as an answer?

Comment: This is probably not what you want to do, but... You could ask for *virtual* vector bundles, and interpret a 'family of virtual vector bundles' as a function $X \to \mathrm{Fred}($\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$)$ to the space of Fredholm operators or something. Then you could restrict attention to measurable functions, and integrate as usual. This doesn't seem like a very good idea though.

Comment: @DylanWilson interesting idea!  I don't know exactly what integrating Fredholm-operator-valued functions would do, but my guess is that it won't do what I want, since the result of the integration would be (presumably) a *single* Fredholm operator, whose "dimension" would be an integer; whereas I need the result to be some kind of thing that can have a non-integral "dimension" in order for it to coincide with the integral of the fiber dimensions.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Bob Paré once had a student named Mike Wendt whose thesis contains a wealth of information about such things from a topos theoretic point of view. He is primarily interested in the case of measurable fields of Hilbert spaces, where everything is messed up by the fact that the ell_2 sum does not have a universal property, but there might be something about measurable fields of vector spaces too. (I don't remember.)

Answer (score 15):

I'll be brief and (happily) add more details on demand
(**Edit:** Some more details were added).

---

**Some Philosophy**

Slogan: *You can do math fibered over a measured space*.

Most of us are already used to the idea of doing algebraic geometry over schemes  and topology over topological spaces, but are less familiar with doing math over measured spaces. Yet, this concept has a long history.
Maybe its first appearance is in the notion of a *bundle of Hilbert spaces over a measured space* aka as [*direct integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_integral) of Hilbert spaces. Also in the theory of von-Neumann algebras one decomposes a general algebra into a direct integral of *factors* (similarly to the way in which an *Azumaya algebra* is decomposed over its center). I find Furstenberg's pov on Ergodic Theory parallel to Grothendieck's pov on Algebraic Geometry in the way spaces are treated relative to a base space, only that Ergodic Theory is somehow more generous in allowing further constructions, due to the flexibility of measurable functions.

In recent decades Zimmer developed the theory of [convex compact spaces](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022123678900137/1-s2.0-0022123678900137-main.pdf?_tid=84d733be-f776-11e7-a644-00000aacb362&acdnat=1515747587_4c48aa700be47a56e6bbf186349126fb), Gaboriau developed the theory of [simplicial complexes](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/gaboriau/Travaux-Publi/Habilitation/Gaboriau-Habilitation.pdf), Sauer developed the theory of [manifolds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605627.pdf), all over a base measured space. This pov is quite common nowadays in Ergodic Theory and there are many more examples.

I should probably mention that in all of the above examples, theories were developed for an external sake. Maybe it is about time for approaching these theories as a whole and develop a master theory. I don't know.

---

**Vector spaces over $X$**

Given a measured spaces $X$ (that is, a standard Borel space endowed with a measure class), a (complex) vector space over $X$ is a Borel space $V$ endowed with a Borel map $\pi:V\to X$ such that the fibers $V_x$ over (a.e) point is endowed with a vector space structure which varies measurably.
A precise axiomatic definition could be given by means of the standard vector space axioms reinterpreted by means of fiber-products constructions. 
For example you have the addition map $V\times_X V \to V$ and the scalar multiplication $\mathbb{C}\times V \to V$ which commute with the obvious maps to 
$X$ and satisfy the obvious compatibility relations.

Whatever is ones definition of "a measurably varying $X$-indexed family of vector spaces" it should be equivalent to a vector space over $X$.
Unfortunately, I haven't seen this definition published anywhere, so let's say it is a [folklore definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_folklore).

Note that associated with $X$ we have the algebra of bounded (measurable, defined up to a.e equivalence) $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions $L^\infty(X)$,
which is a commutative [*von-Neumann algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra) (aka a W*-algebra), that is a C*-algebra which has a predual ($L^1(X)$).

To a vector space over $X$, $\pi:V\to X$, one associates the vector space of all (classes of) measurable sections of $\pi$, to be denoted $L(V)$ (or $L(\pi)$ if there is a danger of misunderstanding).
This is a module over the algebra $L^\infty(X)$.

---

**Dimension**

Assume now that $X$ is actually endowed with a finite measure (not merely a measure class). Then integration is a *finite trace* on the algebra $L^\infty(X)$, and this algebra becomes a *finite von-Neumann algebra*. For modules over such guys there is a well developed notion of dimension, the *von-Neumann dimension*.
For finitely generated projective modules, this dimension is given by taking the trace of a certain projection in a certain matrix algebra over $L^\infty(X)$ (you can guess which projection: a one associated with a presentation of a the module as a direct summand of a free module, which trace is choice independent).
The dimension of a general module is defined as the supremum over the dimensions of its f.g projective submodules. This theory is carried in [Lueck's book](http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9783540435662). For an online survey, see [his paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/dg-ga/9707011.pdf).

Finally, it is an exercise to show that for a vector space over $X$, $\pi:V\to X$, as defined above, we have that the von-Neumann dimension of the $L^\infty(X)$-module $L(V)$ equals exactly $\int_X \dim V_x$.

Comment: Dixmier (in A.73) only defines direct integrals for measurable fields of Hilbert spaces. The Hilbert space structure here is important in that it defines the relevant square-integrability condition. But as the OP has already mentioned in the comments, his vector spaces don't come equipped with an inner product. I've never seen a notion of direct integral for plain vector spaces without any additional structure. What would be a reference for that? (Of course it may well exist and may even be the simpler concept, but it doesn't seem to be covered by the usual notion of direct integral.)

Comment: One can certainly define $\int V_x dx$ by simply omitting any type of integrability condition and this results indeed in an $L^\infty(X)$-module. But unlike in the Hilbert space case, there's no reason to expect it to be finitely generated, which means that von Neumann dimension is generally not applicable. But perhaps one can fix this by considering it as a module over the algebra of *all* integrable function up to a.e. equivalence (while $L^\infty(X)$ only contains essentially bounded ones).

Comment: @TobiasFritz, thanks for the comments. One can define a suitable notion of direct integral of Banach spaces and even more general objects. I am not sure what is the right source for this (maybe Takesaki?), but this is fairly common.

Comment: In any case, regarding finite dimensional vector spaces, measurability of the family also implies that you can impose on it a measurable inner product, so (even if this is not too natural) you could regard it as a family of Hilbert spaces. But let me repeat: this is not necessary, as direct integral of measurable family of f.d vector spaces could be easily defined. I will update my answer with either a reference or an explanation of the construction in the near future.

Comment: Sure, you can equip them with inner products, but then the direct integral will depend on that choice through square-integrability. Anyway, I'm looking forward to an updated answer!

Comment: This is really interesting, and I look forward to the updated answer too.  I'm not sure whether it will do what I want, though, because the category that the object lives in ($L^\infty(X)$-modules) is dependent on $X$, whereas I would hope/expect an "integral over $X$" to *eliminate* any dependence on $X$.  In particular, I want to consider maps between the integrals $\int V_x \;dx$ over different spaces $X$.  But maybe I can put these modules overy varying algebras together into one category somehow.

Comment: Out of curiosity: suppose the base $X$ and the bundle $\pi:V\to X$ are smooth, and the measure is given by a volume form and orientation on $X$, is there also a well known interpretation for $\frac{dV_x}{dx}$ which would make the fundamental theorem of calculus hold when $X$ is an interval?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, I am not aware of such an interpretation. Maybe the place to look for such is in the realm of TQFT (interpenetrating the difference of the boundary value as a $V_a^*\otimes V_b$ or as an operator between these spaces).

Comment: @MikeShulman: Suppose I have a sheaf $V$ over a space $X$.  Then surely the analogous operation is to take $\Gamma(X, V)=\pi_*V$, where $\pi: X\to *$ is the constant map?  This does have the structure of a $\Gamma(X, O_X)$-module, where $O_X$ is the ring of your favorite kind of functions, but one can simply forget this to obtain an object in $Sh(*)$.  So surely the correct thing to do here is to take Uri's operation and forget the module structure, no?

Comment: @DanielLitt But unless I misunderstand, it's only as an $L^\infty(X)$-module that the integral has the correct dimension.